# Specify min max range with specific value placed in a defined level

Tags: math

I'm working on a basic betting system at the moment, and I need the following:

- Specify a minimum and maximum return over X Levels (at present 21. This isn't looking like changing any time soon due to how the rest of the program works)
- Specify a "break even" level (this can change). Level where the player makes their bet back (well, was going to be 90% of their bet, I think their full bet might be nicer)
- Each level has to be higher than the last, no particular scaling, so this should be a bit easier.

I think I've looked at this too much, I can't seem to get the right level for the "break even" level so I'm over complicating it.

Worst case scenario, the minimum can be optional, the most important part are the break even level and maximum, I can always tweak it later on.

Comment: And how do you characterize the break even level? What are your requirements?

Comment: Normally it's the average level everyone gets to, to make it more fair for everyone playing. Though the level number for it would be known before making this curve/scale

Comment: I still have no clue what you want. What are those levels? How is the system supposed to work?

Comment: Sorry, I missed some of the explanation. I guess it's similar to a deal/no deal sort of setup, with an entry fee

-- Player bets $100
-- They keep winning (thus progressing through levels). Each level means higher win
-- Specify maximum to be $100,000
-- Specify level to get their bet back as '10'
`code`
21 -- They win $100,000
20
19
18
17
16
15
14
13
12
11
10 -- They will win $100 back if they take the win now
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1 -- Specify minimum (optional)

Comment: So use any interpolation scheme? Maybe with some exponential base.

Comment: I couldn't get formatting happening because I'm an idiot. Here's an explanation which I hope helps:

They start at level 1. If they keep winning, they'll make their initial bet/entry fee back at level 10 (pre-determined). If they keep going and win every level, they will get the specified maximum ($100,000)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that and see what I come up with for the time being

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to go with another solution. Basically a function that enables me to specify a minimum, maximum and amount of levels in between.

I'll explain it in case other people are looking for something like this.

I found this answer as a basis: [Smooth movement to ascend through the atmosphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706952/smooth-movement-to-ascend-through-the-atmosphere/707035)

That way I can easily adjust the increase of wins and everything else I need